# Promise.map and callback on each resolved

Tags: javascript, dictionary, concurrency, promise, bluebird

I have an array of URLs which I am mapping (with bluebird's Promise.map) to http GET requests with max concurrency set:

```
const fetchingPages = Promise.map(urls, async url => {
  const data = await fetchPage(url)
  return data
}, { concurrency: 100 })
const pages = await fetchingPages
```

How can I listen to each promise being resolved and do some side effect in an organized manner, i.e. don't put side effects inside .map callback?

Ideally, I would like to have array of "empty/dummy" promises ahead of time, so I can set callback to any of them before corresponding GET request is even sent.

I can do it like this:

```
const pagesUtils = urls.map((url) => {
  let resolve, reject
  const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    resolve = res
    reject = rej
  })
  return {
    url,
    promise,
    resolve,
    reject,
  }
})

const pagesPromises = pagesUtils.map(x => x.promise)

Promise.map(urlsFinal, async (url, i) => {
  const data = await fetchPageData(url)
  pagesUtils[i].resolve(data)
  return data
}, { concurrency: CONCURRENCY })

pagesPromises.forEach(p => {
  p.then((result) => {
    // side-effect
    console.log(result)
  })
})

const results = await Promise.all(pagesPromises)
```

How can this be done in ideal way? Thanks.

Comment: *"How can I listen to each promise being resolved and do some side effect in an organized manner, i.e. don't put side effects inside .map callback?"* What's disorganized about doing that? What are you trying to achieve by doing something else?

Comment: I feel like promises should increase composability, but being forced to put all code that might want react to particular promise being resolved inside single callback opposes it.

Comment: I don't see how. You don't have to put the *code* in the `map` callback, you just have to call it from there.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it seems like you're bothered about putting a lot of **code** in the `map` callback. You don't have to, put the various bits of logic into discrete, composable functions as normal, and call them. E.g.:

```
const fetchingPages = Promise.map(urls, async url => {
  let data = await fetchPage(url)
  data = await doThis(data)
  if (/*...some condition...*/) {
    data = await doThat(data)
  }
  return data
}, { concurrency: 100 })
const pages = await fetchingPage
```

(Naturally, you only have to `await` `doThis` or `doThat` if they're also asynchronous.)

Or in promise terms insted of `async`/`await`:

```
const fetchingPages = Promise.map(urls, url => {
  return fetchPage(url)
    .then(doThis)
    .then(data => /*...some condition...*/ ? doThat(data) : data)
}, { concurrency: 100 })
const pages = await fetchingPage
```

Comment: I know I can do this, but I just don't want to "collect" all code that would eventually need to be run once an promise is resolved to one place. I was thinking something along event-handler that @asosnovsky suggested, but I thought I don't need to re-invent this, since I am already using promises, which are designed (I think) so you can register callback anywhere in your code.

Comment: @JozefMikuláš - You could certainly separate the mapping portion from waiting for the overall result (I was thinking of suggesting that at one point). Without concurrency control, it would be simply using `const promises = urls.map(...);` to get the map, then doing anything else you want to hook things up on the promises in that array, then eventually waiting for the result via `Promise.all`. And you could write something to effectively do that but with concurrency control (but I think you would have to write it). FWIW.

Comment: If I didn't need to limit concurrency, I would just directly map array of URLs to array of promises with Array.map, and then do whatever I want with any promise in array. But once I used Promise.map, I lose ability to pass single promises around and register callbacks to then anywhere.

Comment: Ok, at least you know what I am trying to do now. Do you think it's an anti-pattern, or weird thing to do? If there was an actual util that did this, I think it would be quite useful. Is my example solution (in OP) too bad if it was wrapped in utility? Thanks.

Comment: @JozefMikuláš: FWIW, I've never felt the need for it. :-) That doesn't mean I'd call it an anti-pattern.

Comment: I just like callback registering more than placing all the code/function calls inside that one map callback...

Answer (score 0):

How about using a custom event-handler?

```
function URLFetcher(urls) {
    var onCallback = () => {};

    this.on = cb => {
        onCallback = cb;
    }

    this.fetch = () => {
        return Promise.map(urls, async (url, idx) => {
          const data = await fetchPage(url);
          onCallback(idx, url, data);
          return data
        }, { concurrency: 100 })
    }
} 

var fetcher = new URLFetcher(urls);
fetcher.on( (idx, url, data) => {
    console.log(`URL #${idx} i.e ${url} was returned with data`, data);
})
const pages = await fetcher.fetch()
```